# Get the first equal values after sorting

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say I have a list of lists like this one:

```
l = [[3,4], [2,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,2]]
```

How this list can be sorted based on the first element of each sub-list and get a list with the first equal sorted elements, 
e.g. `[[1,2],[1,2]]`?

Comment: There's a function called `sorted` (and a list method called `sort`). Does it do what you want? If not, what does it do wrong?

Comment: Meanwhile, there are a few different ways you can get a list with the first equal sorted elements. You can turn the list into a multiset with `collections.Counter` first and then sort that and take the first result. Or you can use `itertools.groupby` and take the first group. Or you can just write a simple loop that starts off with the first element, and keeps appending the next until you find one that isn't equal to the first.

Comment: each sublist always only has two elements?

Comment: @Spinx Yes it always has two elements

Comment: @abarnert Yes `sort()` and `sorted` work, I just want to get the first equal sorted. Can you give an example?

Comment: I gave you three ways to do it. The first two may be a bit confusing to a novice, but the "write a simple loop", you should at least be able to get started on yourself, and tell us where you got stuck. You know how to create a new list, how to append to a list, how to loop over the elements of a list, how to compare two strings in an `if` statement, etc., right?

Comment: The for ..loop to get the first elements, I had it already in my mind. I was looking for smarter ways. Thank you for your reply. I take it as resolved

Comment: If you want to learn about smarter ways (although they may not actually be smarter for a use-case this simple…), I can show how to do it with a groupby or a Counter, to give you something to dive into learning more deeply. Check out the docs on both and see if either one looks like it's something you want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, not optimized at all but easily readable and understandable, without any additional package to import:

```
l = [[3,4], [2,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,2]]

# Sort by first then second element of sub-lists
l.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))
print(l)

# Get a list with the first equal sorted sub-lists
s = [l[0]]* l.count(l[0])
print(s)
```

Comment: Why are you passing a key that just explicitly turns a 2-element list into a 2-element tuple that will sort the same way as the original list?

Comment: @abamert You're right, sir ! I could have used `l.sort()` instead of `l.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))`, but I found a very little bit more explicit like that.

Comment: It seems not correct, consider this list `[[3,4], [2,3], [3,4],[1,2], [1,3], [1,2]]`, As OP decribed, first equal should be `[3,4]` instead of `[1,2]`

Comment: @Sphinx it should be [1,2], in the question it says "sorted based on the first element"

Comment: Actually, "sorted by the first element" is not the same as "sorted by all elements"; you should presumably sort to `[[1,2], [1,3], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]` (assuming a stable sort). So, presumably, with `[[1,3], [1,2], [1,2], [1,3]]` the output should be `[[1,3], [1,3]]` (which your code would do if you changed the `key` to `lambda x: x[0]` with no other changes, although it would still be quadratic time).

Answer (score -1):

First you can find all the doubles:

```
l = [x for n, x in enumerate(l) if x in l[:n]]
```

And then you can sort by the first element using:

```
l = sorted(l)
```

It's faster than if you do it the other way around, especially if l is very long I would first reduce it to the minimal list and then sort.

If you have items appear three times, this will return a list with those items in there twice. You can remove this with:

```
l = [x for n, x in enumerate(l) if x not in l[:n]]
```

Largely based on another answer from @georg .